# How to achieve PHPUnitTest with assertions on GIT?

Tags: php, git, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a GITWrapper which maintains a GIT directory. For a couple of tests I need those things:

- A directory with GIT
- One initial commit containing no file
- One commit containing a couple of new files
- One commit containing some changes to the files

My GitWrapper now walks over the history and does something. So I need to test such things. Example:

> The precondition / GitHistory is as above.
>   The GitWrapper should point out some differences in the file system and its content.

Those are things I need to test but don't know how. I guess there is some simple or common solution like using vfsStream or other helper which I yet don't know. So these questions come to my mind:

- How would you achieve this Repo in a UnitTest?
- Where would the repository be placed?
- And how to rollback repo changes for the next test?

I would love to see a common way to solve this. vfsStream might be a solution but I am not very sure what is the right solution for these kinds of pre-conditions.

Comment: Could you provide some examples, because problem is complicaded.

Comment: Just added more details to it. In search for the general way I altered some problems/examples.

Comment: Do you want to do unit tests or integration tests? So do you want to call the real git executables in your tests?

Comment: Damn Gerd K you are right :D It's an integration test. I shouldn't even worry about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- If the setup for the test repo is short, I would suggest to simply write a script that does the required actions. Something like :

  ```
  # file setup.sh :
  #!/bin/sh

  repo=$1

  # create the repo :
  mkdir -p $1
  cd $1
  git init

  # first empty commit :
  git commit --allow-empty -m 'first commit'

  # second commit : a couple of new files
  echo "Foo" > bar.txt
  echo "Hello" > world.txt
  git add -A
  git commit -m 'second commit'

  # etc ...
  ```

Setting up your unit test would be something like :

```
exec('unittest/git/setup.sh', '/tmp/randomString'):
```

Tearing it down :

```
exec('rm', '-rf', '/tmp/randomString');
```

- If the setup you want is bigger : make a git repo with your setup, and simply clone it somewhere in `/tmp` at the beginning of your unit test,  and remove it afterwards.

  ```
  // setup
  exec('git', 'clone', 'path/or/url/to/initial/setup', '/tmp/randomString');

  // teardown
  exec('rm', '-rf', '/tmp/randomString');
  ```